# Manga with a fantasy tourney theme

Tags: story-identification, manga

Its basically about a tournament to gather the strongest to determine who will go fight the demon king. The characters that I remember are a 3-armed humanoid wyvern that amassed a huge arsenal of legendary weapons that he uses to fight and a isekaied Japanese swordsman who got so strong Earth yeeted him to another world. Doesn't have a specific MC I think. It just jumps from one PoV to another. Also the characters got cool titles.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  How long was it?

Comment: I read it this year on mangadex. As for how long it is, it was still ongoing when i was reading it and it was not a one-shot. To add more, the japanse swordsman was introduced fighting an ancient golem and got informed of the tourney by a girl that got so freaked out with his power that she wished him and all other freaks that gather for the tourney kill each other

Comment: Is the tournament basically the entire story, and not just one specific arc? Does it start right away, e.g. in the first chapter? Were some/most/all of the participants gods or legendary humans from mythology? Was it a parody, or played straight? It's still ongoing, but do you remember how many chapters there were when you read it?

Comment: The tourney is basically the plot with some flashbacks of the characters. The tourney doesnt start right on ch 1 since the first couple chapters were introducing the swordsman snd wyvern dude. There were no if not few inspiration from myths i think. Basically new fantasy characters. I dont remember the amount of chapters but i think it was more  than 10

Comment: Can you confirm this is a Japanese black&white manga, and not a full-color Korean/Chinese webtoon? I'm guessing it is since you mentioned a Japanese swordsman, but I'd like to check.

Comment: Yep,  black and white jap manga.

Answer (score 3):

The manga I was thinking of is *Ishura - Shin Maou Sensou* (*Ishura - New Demon King War*). There's only 3 chapters in English.

> The Demon King, who terrorized the world for twenty-five years, was slain. However, the Hero who killed him never came forward. Therefore, in order to decide on the "True Hero" that will be acknowledged by everyone as the strongest, sixteen "Asuras", masters of extraordinary abilities, are gathered in the great kingdom of the Yellow Capital! "Insta-Kill Blade", "Almighty Magic", "Absolute Defense"… The ultimate deathmatch for the title of the strongest in another world begins now!
>
> <sub>[Mangadex](https://mangadex.org/title/77a51837-c2d0-479d-9de8-25942b404d4f/ishura-shin-maou-sensou)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for letting us know the answer and coming back to post it as such! Note that as it has been more than 48 hours since you posts your question you can also accept your answer by clicking the checkmark next to it alongside the voting buttons!

Answer (score 1):

In case the original querent doesn't return, they stated that they found the manga in question, [*Ishura*](https://yenpress.com/9781975337865/ishura-vol-1/):

[image: Cover image of Ishura]

> In a world where the Demon King has died, a host of demigods capable of felling him have inherited the world. A master fencer who can figure out how to take out their opponents with a single glance; a lancer so swift they can break the sound barrier; a wyvern rogue who fights with three legendary weapons at once; an all-powerful wizard who can speak thoughts into being; an angelic assassin who deals instant death. Eager to attain the title of “True Hero,” these champions each pursue challenges against formidable foes and spark conflicts among themselves. The battle to determine the mightiest of the mighty begins.